# Mock an object that should do an action in its constructor with MoQ

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq

I've a class that is doing a very specific job: instantiate an object and ensure that the object is disposed on the same thread it has been created(I've some locks that require this behavior, but this is not the subject).

```
ManagedLifeCycleObjectInstantier<SomeType> myInstance = ManagedLifeCycleObjectInstantier<SomeType>.Instantiate()){
myInstance.InstantiatedObject //Here my instantiated object is available

//Some other thread calls
//Then when the instantier is disposed, it ensure that the instance also get disposed, but on the correct thread.
myInstance.Dispose();
```

I would like to UnitTest my `ManagedLifeCycleObjectInstantier`, one of my case is that there is an exception thrown from the constructor of `SomeType`, I've to make sure that I receive this exception and that the `ManagedLifeCycleObjectInstantier` doesn't stay stuck on this.

Comment: Could You add Thread property to the ManagedLifeCycleObjectInstantier's Mock? This way You could assert, that ManagedLifeCycleObjectInstantier's `this.Thread.ManagedThreadId == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` in the Dispose

Comment: @ntohl Not sure why it's relevant? My question is how to give a specific behavior inside the constructor with MoQ, because I need to raise some kind of exception and ensure that my instantier has the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a full mock. Just create a class for testing that throws in it's constructor and

```
Assert.That(
    () => ManagedLifeCycleObjectInstantiator.Instantier<MyType>(),
    Throws.TypeOf<MyException>());
```

For the thread test, it's not clear what you want to test. What is supposed to happen if you dispose it on the wrong thread?

Comment: It's not the question. I know doing that, but I've several(10+) cases in my mind which would require everytime a new dummy class with a different constructor content.